# YUI: Aligning the baseline of a YUI button with the text next to it

Tags: css, yui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning the baseline of a YUI button with the baseline of the text next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036665/aligning-the-baseline-of-a-yui-button-with-the-baseline-of-the-text-next-to-it)

I'd like to display a YUI button next to some text, but the baseline of the YUI button text does not line up with the baseline of the text next to it. My text size and font for both the button text and text next to it is identical.

If I use a plain HTML button the text baselines correctly line up.

You can see a live example of this at http://jsbin.com/ukuqo

How would I get the baselines to line up using CSS?

*I am reposting here a question that was orginaly posted by another developer on the YUI list, and which didn't receive any answer there.*