# Rounded input boxes with YUI

Tags: javascript, css, yui

Would it be possible to use YUI to change all my input boxes to have rounded corners? I cannot use a background image as  the inputs will be variable width and I cannot add divs wrapped around them because some input elements are generated. Also I cannot use border radius or any moz/webkit variation as it needs to appear the same in IE6.

Any pointers appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There [multiple techniques to make cross-browser rounded corners](http://www.infernodevelopment.com/5-methods-css-curvy-corners), and YUI can certainly be used to convert `input` elements on the fly, adding wrapper `div`s if needed to support the method you choose to use.

Here is a [YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) implementation of rounded corners for a `text`-type `input`, using background images for the corners:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stack Overflow 1471254</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roundMyCorners.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0b1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Here is an input box: <input type="text" value="type stuff" class="roundMyCorners"> Thanks!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       YUI({combine: true, timeout: 10000}).use("node", function(Y) {
          Y.all('body input.roundMyCorners').each(function(rcInput) {
             var outerDiv = Y.Node.create('<div class="roundMyCornersOuterDiv"></div>');
             outerDiv.appendChild(Y.Node.create('<div class="tl"></div>'));
             outerDiv.appendChild(Y.Node.create('<div class="tr"></div>'));
             outerDiv.appendChild(rcInput.cloneNode());
             outerDiv.appendChild(Y.Node.create('<div class="bl"></div>'));
             outerDiv.appendChild(Y.Node.create('<div class="br"></div>'));
             rcInput.get('parentNode').replaceChild( outerDiv, rcInput );
          });
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS file. For demo purposes, I'm (somewhat rudely) hotlinking the PNGs from a [site that has a rounded corner demo](http://www.bestinclass.com/blog/2008/css3-border-radius-rounded-corners-ie/) in this code. Of course it's preferable to make your own images for your site.

```
.roundMyCorners {
   width: 12em;
   border: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   background-color: #3f6daf;
}
.roundMyCornersOuterDiv {
   position: relative;
   display: -moz-inline-stack;  /* inline-block for older Gecko */
   display: inline-block;
   *zoom: 1;  /* force hasLayout for IE */
   *display: inline;  /* rendered as inline-block in IE after hasLayout */
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 6px;
   color: white;
   background-color: #3f6daf;
}
.roundMyCornersOuterDiv .tl {
   position: absolute;
   width: 6px;
   height: 6px;
   background: url(http://www.bestinclass.com/images/ui/rounded/colhead-tl.png) top left no-repeat;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.roundMyCornersOuterDiv .tr {
   position: absolute;
   width: 6px;
   height: 6px;
   background: url(http://www.bestinclass.com/images/ui/rounded/colhead-tr.png) top right no-repeat;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
.roundMyCornersOuterDiv .bl {
   position: absolute;
   width: 6px;
   height: 6px;
   background: url(http://www.bestinclass.com/images/ui/rounded/colhead-bl.png) bottom left no-repeat;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.roundMyCornersOuterDiv .br {
   position: absolute;
   width: 6px;
   height: 6px;
   background: url(http://www.bestinclass.com/images/ui/rounded/colhead-br.png) bottom right no-repeat;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Of course, the styles for the `tl`, `tr`, `bl`, `br` and even the `roundMyCornersOuterDiv` classes could be set via JavaScript. I left them in the CSS here for clarity.

Note that if you want to change **all** the `input` elements, you just change the initial selector from '`body input.roundMyCorners`' to '`input`'. However, I don't expect this to work nicely for `checkbox` and `radio` types of `input`, so perhaps '`input[type="text"]`' is a better selector, if you want to avoid stamping class names everywhere.

One other note: since `input` is an inline element, I wanted the wrapper `div` to be `inline-block`. This is essential for [popular techniques for table-free form layouts](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/tableless_forms/P20/). Unfortunately, this required a couple of proprietary tweaks.

Finally, if you don't want to fuss with the CSS or maintain your own YUI/jQuery/whatever code, you could try [Nifty Corners](http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html) or [Curvy Corners](http://www.curvycorners.net/), which are JavaScript libraries that claim to do this sort of thing automagically, at least for `div`s. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a selector to find the inputs and then replace them with divs around the inputs?